# Domain based redirect to different PHP files via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Domain based redirect to different PHP files via htaccess

Hello there.
Here's the thing:
I have two domains here [http://www.myproject.com and
[http://www.myproject.com.br   .. In my root folder i have all the stuff for
my projects including two "indexes": "index-en.php" for english and
"index.php" for portuguese.

Can i have some trick in htaccess that redirect my users to one
of these files depending on domain? .. something like:

[http://www.myproject.com [OR]
[http://myproject.com redirect to [http://www.myproject.com/index-en.php

and

[http://www.myproject.com.br [OR] [http://myproject.com.br redirect to
[http://www.myproject.com.br/index.php

??

Sorry if this is a stupid question but im almost crazy looking for tutorials over
the internet and i cant get something that works or some response if this is possible or just a stupid question .. Can someone please give me some direction? 
Maybe some solution with a conditional directoryIndex (I dont know if that's possible).

thanks a lot

Actually i have this in my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myproject.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myproject.com/index-en.php [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myproject.com.br$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myproject.com.br/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This just does the "non www to www" - that works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want. The `RewriteCond` trickery is probably a bit overkill here, but it does make adding extra languages easier:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/index.php    \.com\.br/(index.php)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}/index-en.php \.com/(index-en.php)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1
```

Comment: Me again =|
I've just noticed that my "ErrorDocument 404 /404.php" isn't working anymore ... it is possible to fix this? 

Thanks a lot again anyway.

Comment: @Fabio - Ah, whoops. You might want to try changing `RewriteRule ^ %1` to `RewriteRule ^$ %1`, and see if that fixes things.

Comment: @Tim - Yes! (laughing) That fixed it!
I'll post something about your help in my blog to thank you. 
You really saved me here man.

Comment: Here's the post http://www.paespedro.com.br/blog/mercado/domain-based-redirect-to-different-php-files-via-htaccess. Sorry it's in Portuguese, i'm just saying that im happy that we have people just like you and others here that really helps who's in need. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  myproject\.com$
RewriteRule ^/$  /index-en.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  myproject\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/$  /index.php
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.
That didnt seems to work.. i removed my actual RewriteConds and Rules and put yours but nothing seems to change (The "non www to www" does'nt work anymore)